# Android: IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 24929, col 0 from CursorWindow

Tags: android, sqlite, illegalstateexception

I need help with this error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 24929, col 0 from CursorWindow. 
Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it
```

In this code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select id from " + pTable, null);

if (res != null) {
    if (res.getCount() != 0) {
        res.moveToFirst();
        int id;
        while (!res.isAfterLast()) {
            id = res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("id")); // <-- Error was here
            // ...
            res.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    res.close();
}
```

This code works sometimes, but when I have many rows (like 25k rows) I get this Exception. 
Is it a Android restriction?

Could you help me with that?
Thanks!

Comment: Try this - `if (res != null) {  

        int id;
        while (res.moveToNext()) {
            id = res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("id")); // <-- Error was here
            // ...
    }
    res.close();
}`

Comment: The theoretical maximum number of rows in a table is (18446744073709551616 or about 1.8e+19)

Comment: Your table probably doesn't have an `id` column?

Answer (score -1):

```
 public ArrayList<Model> Name(){
    ArrayList<Model> ModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + pTable,null );
    while (c.moveToNext()){
        String id = c.getString(0);
 return ModelList;
}
```